# Problemas com um contêiner de Injeção de Dependência - Simple Injector

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Estou montando meu contêiner de ID usando o Simple Injector, mas está dando um erro de compilação (Sublinhado de vermelho) na config.  da Interface IReadOnlyRepository com a classe ClienteDapperRepository. Acho que estou fazendo algo de errado mas não sei o que é rsrsrs.

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

//Códigos

```
    public static Container RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        //Domain to Repository

        container.Register<IReadOnlyRepository, ClienteDapperRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        return container;
    }



     public interface IReadOnlyRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
     {
         TEntity Get(int id);
         IEnumerable<TEntity> All();
         IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
     }



    public class ClienteDapperRepository : Common.Repository, IClienteReadOnlyRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Cliente> All()
        {
            using (var cn = SistemaComercialConnection)
            {
                var cliente = cn.Query<Cliente>("Select * from Cliente");
                return cliente;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: O nome não está errado?

Comment: Estão certos os nomes, só que ele não aceita essa estrutura... Não sei se teria outra maneira...

Comment: pode enviar o código de erro?

Comment: Se eu deixar como está, ele apenas fica sublinhado de vermelho. Se eu alterar para container.Register<IReadOnlyRepository<Cliente>, ClienteDapperRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped); Ele gera este erro:  "+  $exception {"To be able to use the Lifestyle.Scoped property, please ensure that the container is configured with a default scoped lifestyle by setting the Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle property with the required scoped lifestyle for your type of application. See: https://simpleinjector.org/lifestyles#scoped"} System.InvalidOperationException
"

Comment: Por favor, poste o código em vez de imagens. E se você olhar no output do build, verá o erro, poste ele também

Comment: Acho que a forma que estou fazendo está errada...

Comment: o teu segundo register não teria que ficar semelhante ao primeiro? Ficando algo do tipo `container.Register(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(ClienteDapperRepository<>, Lifestyle.Scope)`

Comment: Eu postei o código Pessoal.

Comment: Eu tentei assim: container.Register(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(ClienteDapperRepository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped); mas ele sublinha de vermelho o ClienteDapperRepository.

Comment: De repente da erro pq tua classs ClienteDapperRepository não é genérica, sendo assim, tem que ficar da seguinte forma `container.Register(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(ClienteDapperRepository), Lifestyle.Scoped);`

Comment: Se eu fosse usar o Ninject, bastaria usar:  Bind<IReadOnlyRepository<Genre>>().To<GenreDapperRepository>(); que funcionaria.... Só que no SimpleInjector deve ter lá alguma diferença...

Comment: Pablo, funcionou mano!!!!!!!! Muito obrigado cara!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Responde lá no tópico da pergunta para que eu possa marcar como resposta.. :)

Comment: Só acho que você poderia melhorar sua pergunta tirando as imagens e colocando a mensagem de erro que você tinha. Mas deixando o código.

Comment: Acabei de editá-la! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é que a sua chamada ao `container.Register` está errada, você está tentando fazer a injeção de dependência usando como se o register fosse generico, onde o correto é que ele espera 3 parâmetros, tendo que ficar da seguinte forma a sua injeção de dependência.

```
container.Register(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(ClienteDapperRepository), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```