# Dúvida sobre como Mapear uma Interface com uma classe - SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Estou tendo problemas ao mapear a `Interface IClienteRepository` com a classe `ClienteRepository`. Ao compilar a aplicação, aparece este erro:

> "exception {"To be able to use the Lifestyle.Scoped property, please ensure that the container is configured with a default scoped lifestyle by setting the Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle property with the required scoped lifestyle for your type of application. See: https://simpleinjector.org/lifestyles#scoped"} System.InvalidOperationException"

Como resolver?

```
public static Container RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        //Domain to Repository

        container.Register<IClienteRepository, ClienteRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        return container;
    }

public interface IClienteRepository : IRepository<Cliente>
    {
    }

public class ClienteRepository : Repository<Cliente>, IClienteRepository
    {
        public ClienteRepository(SistemaComercialContext context)
            :base(context)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Essa não é a mesma que te respondi ontem

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problemas com um contêiner de Injeção de Dependência - Simple Injector](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260736/problemas-com-um-cont%c3%aainer-de-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-depend%c3%aancia-simple-injector)

Comment: problema parecido, mas agora é outra situação envolvendo Interface e classe...

Comment: Pelo que estou lendo na documentação, após registrar todas as dependências no container, eles chamam um `container.Verify()` e não passam o `Lifestyle`, ficando algo do tipo o register `container.Register<IClienteRepository, ClienteRepository>();`

Comment: Acredito que para utilizar o escopo que você definiu, tenha que fazer a seguinte chamada após instanciar o container `container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme pude observar na documentação do [simpleinjector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#scoped), para você utilizar o `Lifestyle.Scoped`, você precisa antes de tudo ter certeza que a opção `continer.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle` esteja configurada adequadamente.

Ficando algo do tipo

```
public static Container RegisterServices(Container container)
{
    // Set the scoped lifestyle one directly after creating the container
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();          
    //Domain to Repository

    container.Register<IClienteRepository, ClienteRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    return container;
}
```